# MUI React Theme palette contrastText doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm using MUI React to create a menu and I used the `AppBar` component.
I want to customize in this way:

```js
brown.myBrown = '#544846';
const brownTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: brown.myBrown,
            contrastText: grey[50]
        }
    }
});
```

The contrastText field doesn't work and the result is a brown appBar with also text color brown as show here:

[Screenshot of AppBar component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hembm.png)
The menu items are visibile only when I hover on them.

How can I change the item color in `grey[50]`?

Answer (score 1):

The value of contrastText only gets applied if you set the color property as follows in your AppBar component:

```
<AppBar color={'primary'}>
```

(Or to 'secondary' if you want to use the corresponding contrastText value.)

If you don't want to set that property you can also use this approach:

```
const theme = useTheme();
...
<AppBar [...] sx={{color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText}}>
```

color doesn't set the background-color but the color of descendants.